# Three decimals showing as 4 decimals in dataset

Tags: asp.net

I am using oracle database. I have a table called TBLTRANSACTIONS and it has AMOUNT column whose data type is NUMBER(18,3).

I am storing amount values with 3 decimals like as shown below
AMOUNT

12.345

10.432

Now i am fetching table data using dataadapter.fill(ds);

My problem is when i observed data in dataset, The amount filed data showing with 4 decimals like as shown below.

AMOUNT

12.3450

10.4320

My requirement is i want to show data to the user as it is in my table with 3 decimals.

Please suggest

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: How exactly are you viewing the data - in a GridView? It's possible to format the values as you want as you display them.

Comment: How you store data and how you display data are two different things. 12.3450 is the same number as 12.345 so when you are storing it there is no way to differentiate the two (because there aren't really two, just one). When you display the number if you don't specify a format it will use a default one. So if you have definite format requirements you should specify that. The link from VDWWD above is one way but depending on how you are displaying the data you might need to do something else.